# Why is my UINavigtionController bar getting incorrectly positioned on iOS 7 only when I override it?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ios7, uinavigationcontroller

Note: This problem seems to occur after modal views are dismissed.

I am subclassing my `UINavigationController` to make it so that it can't be rotated when on a view that contains navigation. Here is what the code looks like... very simple. I just set my `UINavigationController` class in Interface Builder to `NavViewController`:

```
#import "NavViewController.h"

@interface NavViewController ()

@end

@implementation NavViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return NO;
}

@end
```

The problem is, this is causing my top bar position to get messed up when coming back from a modal view. For example, here is what it looks like when I navigate to the view (Just FYI: the black on the top status bar is built into the background image for the Nav bar):

[image]

Then on my view controller with the Nav bar on it, I call this code to get a picture from the photo album:

```
- (IBAction)goToPhotoAlbum
{
    UIImagePickerController *mypicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    mypicker.delegate = self;
    mypicker.allowsEditing = NO;
    mypicker.wantsFullScreenLayout = YES;
    mypicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
    [self presentViewController:mypicker animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

and then I dismiss it:

```
- (void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

When the view reappears, the Nav bar now looks like this:

[image]

When I comment out the following code from my Nav subclass, like so, everything seems to work fine again and the bar is positioned correctly:

```
/*
    - (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
    {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
    }

    - (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
    {
        return NO;
    }
*/
```

Anyone know what is going on here and how I can maybe fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question:

This is actually a duplicate of [Navigation bar overlapped by status bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14969356/navigation-bar-overlapped-by-status-bar)

The fix was to change my code in the subclass to this:

```
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return YES;
}
```